# Spark mongo connection taking long time then expected

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I need to bring some data from MongoDB in spark job. I used spark mongo connector from *mongo-spark-connector_2.11*. 
Written below code and run it in spark-shell to test

```
def createReadConfig(topic: String): ReadConfig = {
    val user =UserId
    val pass = Password
    val host = Host
    val db = Database
    val coll = Collection
    val partitioner = MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner
    ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> ("mongodb://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + host + "/" + 
    db), "database" -> db, "collection" -> coll, "partitioner" -> partitioner))
}


val collectionRDD= MongoSpark.load(sc,admissionConfig)

collectionRDD.filter(doc=>doc.getObjectId("_id")==new ObjectId("objectId")).count
```

It took more then 20 Sec to give result, whereas same query took less then a sec in mongo console.

Why is this happening, and how can the speed disparity be reduced?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this happening, and how can the speed disparity be reduced?

The difference is, executing `RDD.filter()` load the data from MongoDB to the Spark workers and then performed the `filter` operation. Depending on your network, data size, MongoDB server and Spark sorkers, this may take more time compared to performing a query match via `mongo shell`.

You could utilise `withPipeline` feature of MongoDB Connector for Spark to leverage this, for example:

```
val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)

val aggregatedRDD = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { '_id' : 'some id' } }")))
```

The above would filter data and perform aggregations in MongoDB before passing documents to Spark. This reduce the transfer of data from your MongoDB Server to Spark workers, and also add the ability to utilise database index.

See also [MongoDB Spark Connector: Filters and Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/)

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the part - "the ability to utilise database index."
Is it possible to utilise the appropriate index using withPipeline feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can profile mongodb query to check the difference.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
db.system.profile.find().limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()
```

when use Spark RDD, Looks whole collection is pulled from database:

```
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "test.scenter_inventory_center_sc_stock_sku",
    "command" : {
        "aggregate" : "scenter_inventory_center_sc_stock_sku",
        "pipeline" : [ ],
        "cursor" : {

        },
        "$db" : "test",
        "$readPreference" : {
            "mode" : "primaryPreferred"
        }
    },
    "cursorid" : NumberLong("8629727736555097197"),
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 311,
    "numYield" : 2,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(8)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(4)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(4)
            }
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 101,
    "responseLength" : 26058,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 1,
    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-08-28T06:23:45.089Z"),
    "client" : "172.17.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

when use Mongo RDD, Looks condition exist in the query(**`pipeline`**):

```
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "test.scenter_inventory_center_sc_stock_sku",
    "command" : {
        "aggregate" : "scenter_inventory_center_sc_stock_sku",
        "pipeline" : [
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "warehouse_code" : {
                        "$eq" : "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "cursor" : {

        },
        "$db" : "test",
        "$readPreference" : {
            "mode" : "primaryPreferred"
        }
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 311,
    "cursorExhausted" : true,
    "numYield" : 2,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(8)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(4)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(4)
            }
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 74,
    "responseLength" : 19248,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 1,
    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
    "ts" : ISODate("2018-08-28T06:23:53.735Z"),
    "client" : "172.17.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```